# How to solve $a(\exp(b/x)-1)=c(\exp(b/(x-d))-1)$ for $x$?

Tags: numerical-methods, physics, exponential-function

How to solve $a(\exp\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)-1)=c(\exp\left(\frac{b}{x-d}\right)-1)$ for $x$?
where $a,b,c,d$ can be treated as constants.

This problem is a simplified version of dividing the Planck's equations of $2$ different conditions.
$$B=\frac{2hc^2}{(\lambda^5)\left(\exp\left(\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}\right)-1\right)}$$
I want to find the emissivity of some material, and I think I have to find the temperature of as least $1$ condition for calculation (the temperature difference between $2$ conditions is known). I tried to solve for $T$, but I found it cannot be solved normally. Some suggested numerical methods but I don't really know how to do it. Please help.

Comment: I formatted the equation (and simplified the ^{-1}) to read better, but it was ambiguous if both terms after the / went in the denominator or if only the first one did. If what's there is wrong, please fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to here and I don't know about the format